# Apache/2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04 - Invalid command 'AuthName'

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, apache2

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

The version of Apache HTTP that I am running is 2.4.18.

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26
```

These are the following modules that are loaded into the web server:

```
Loaded Modules:
core_module (static)
so_module (static)
watchdog_module (static)
http_module (static)
log_config_module (static)
logio_module (static)
version_module (static)
unixd_module (static)
mpm_prefork_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
access_compat_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
include_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
ext_filter_module (shared)
mime_magic_module (shared)
expires_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
usertrack_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
vhost_alias_module (shared)
negotiation_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
actions_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
info_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
```

I have loaded the `authn_core` module which provides the functionality that I am going to describe below:

```
a2enmod authn_core
Module authn_core already enabled
```

However, the following error is been returned:

```
Invalid command 'AuthName', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

The same error is returned for `AuthName` and the directives that are relating to authentication.

What am I doing incorrectly and how can I fix this? Is this auth stuff deprecated or implemented differently in Apache HTTP 2.4?

Comment: Where did you place the directive? Show the corresponding part of the config file.

Comment: Until it does not show in the list of installed modules it is not being loaded. As a fallback, add it manually to your config if the ubuntu script "a2enmod" is not being reliable for you. Note that a2enmod and all similar scripts are not official and just provided by Debian-like distributions